# Some sites require that you accept cookies in order to use them. Does this mean that they can read/track my real IP?

Tags: cookies

The site I want to use says that it stores permanent cookies on my computer to track various things, for instance if I have two accounts with them. It says "Please note
that if you set your browser to disable cookies, you may not be able to access certain parts of the Site for example applying for a job or posting a job. Other parts of the Site may also not work properly." Can I use it with TOR and will it get my real IP because of these persistent cookies?

Comment: The moment you open any website they already got your:
------------------------------------------------------ - IP Browser name and OS (If it is sent in your headers) - Previous website visited (If referral headers are accepted) - Request type (GET, POST, DELETE, etc) ---------- 178.154.243.92 - - [21/Jan/2015:23:04:14 +0200] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 865 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; http://yandex.com/bots)" So, basically, the moment you open any website even if you BLOCK all cookies, your IP is still being revealed.

Comment: Thank you, I understand there are a lot of ways for them to get info about me; but for the specific problem I described in my first comment to Mark's post, what would be the best solution? I really need your help as this is a source of income for me and I did not do anything wrong to get blocked.

Comment: Unfortunately, nobody can tell you how to deal with this specific site without knowing how their mechanism works, which is why guidance on breaking specific systems is off topic here.  Tor may or may not help.  They may block it, flag it, or identify you using other means.  Unless you know for sure, you can only a) try different access methods to see if they work or b) play by their rules, whatever rules those may be.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I did play by their rules, in fact I still don't know why I was blocked, by I have a strong suspicion it's because both myself and my husband have separate freelancing accounts and for some reason they don't like to see two account from the same IP. Perhaps they think I am trying to log in under a different name. If I could talk to them I would explain, but they're unresponsive so far.

Comment: From what i understand all you want to do is be able to create news accounts and avoid banning for using same ip for two accounts? If yes i can tell you how , i do not think you have to "play by the rules" its your PC and persistent cookies are invasive unethical and the choice for anything should always belong to YOU. Just clarifies to me what you want and i can write an answer

Comment: Also providing the link to the specific site can helps too

Answer (score 3):

Not inherently, no.

Cookies and IP addresses are independent.  However, if you use the same browser for Tor and non-Tor access to the site, the same cookies will be sent both times, negating any benefit you would otherwise gain from using Tor.

Tor is not a cure-all for anonymity issues, it's merely one tool to use.  There are many ways you can be tracked other than through your IP address, both technical (eg. logging in to an account known to belong to you) and social (eg. personality traits known to be associated with you).  Gaining anonymity with Tor requires understanding these methods and how to counter them.  See, for example, the [Tails warning page](https://tails.boum.org/doc/about/warning/index.en.html).

Comment: Thank you. I am not a programmer and what I am trying to do is offer services on a freelancing site. They have suspended my account because (I suspect) both myself and my husband have accounts and it detected two different logins from the same computer. The block was automatic. There is no way to discuss this with them as they don't really get back to you other than say "We'll look into it." From other users' experience the block disappeared in two months - too long for me. I need a way to create a new account with them so that their system can't connect my new account with the blocked one.

Comment: Someone suggested using Firefox Portabe, because "It is totally self contained and does not write anything to your registry or use your existing profile" (so it won't copy zombie cookies). If I install TOR, then Firefox Portable, and only use that browser to access the freelancing site, will that solve my problem?

Comment: It sounds like it may take care of the technical aspects, but not the social ones.  Further, most websites consider block evasion to be a worse offense than whatever the original block was for -- by evading a two-month block, you risk the block becoming permanent if you're caught.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use the TOR Browser Bundle, you would be using a browser that starts fresh every time that it runs with a new IP. It will also block plugins to prevent your real IP from being discovered through them. However, you could get banned for using TOR to have an account, because someone else may log in with the same IP address or they could just block TOR exit nodes to prevent abuse.

Answer (score 0):

The internet works in a set of layers. Each one supposedly independent of one another. Up at the top, where the session layer sits, the cookies are meant to maintain the identity of the web user. Since IP addresses can shift and change, what people are really interested in is the identity associated with the cookie itself, which is why you see so much effort in creating and maintaining persistent cookies - these are the tokens that enable everything on the interactive web to work.

The use of the tor networks do not provide full anonymity. They provide good enough security but are not completely anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can see your IP address and even more but that's not because of their cookies but rather other avenues (e.g, your headers sent from browser).

However the words "persistent or permanent" + cookies add a deeper cause of concern, because this means that even if you set your browser to delete cookies after each close or manually tell it to delete cookies, the cookie will regenerate itself again even without visiting the website again (I could give you a deep technically explanation for this but I won't - if you want to know more about this read about on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evercookie)).

No, using TOR will not add any benefit but rather call more attention to you and as Wikipedia states "In 2013, a top-secret NSA document was leaked by Edward Snowden [3](https://www.whitehatsec.com/resource/grossmanarchives/10grossmanarchives/101310evercookie.HTML) citing Evercookie as a method of tracking Tor users." If you log on your account via TOR they'll know it is you...

But don't give up on your privacy yet! There are some things you can do to delete these nasty cookies.

Unfortunately I'm too tired to write a tutorial for Firefox and Chrome now so I'll add links where you can see step by step what you can do and anyone feel free to edit my answer and add it if want.

[For Firefox](http://phersung.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/how-to-defeat-evercookie-in-firefox.html) on Chrome you can't do that automatically (I think Google does not really want to fix this since its a old problem) so you will have to manually clear folders  [see here](https://www.whitehatsec.com/resource/grossmanarchives/10grossmanarchives/101310evercookie.HTML).

I have found an interesting open-source software that claims to combat evercookies automatically on many browsers [github download](https://github.com/az0/bleachbit) and the [claims](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/news/bleachbit-081-evercookie).